# Filter Library on SharePoint Foundation 2010 based on user membership

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory

I'm trying to filter the rows of a Document Library on a SharePoint Foundation 2010. I would like to filter depending on the user:

Department of the user
I don't mind if that is done via AD groups memberships, or maybe getting some user parameters from Active Directory.

Comment: I think Audience Targeting based on global audience is not supported in foundation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few user-related fields in a document library (out-of-the-box) - these are: 'Created By', 'Modified By' and 'Checked Out To'. Any additional user information from Active Directory (or other sources) will have to be brought in (i.e., as a site columns/content types). Some customizations will be needed to add these columns and add them to the views.

Details on importing User Profiles via AD can be found here - [How to import user profile information of enabled user accounts from Active Directory to SharePoint](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827754). [UPDATE: Not applicable for SharePoint Foundation]

More on views & filtering are given in this post - [SharePoint 2010 Document Library Views and Styles](http://www.bfcnetworks.com/sharepoint-2010-document-library-view-and-styles/).

UPDATE: 
I think the first step would be access AD and populate the required information within SharePoint -

[Use PowerShell Cmdlets to Search Active Directory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/12/20/use-powershell-cmdlets-to-search-active-directory.aspx)

[Use PowerShell to Query Active Directory from the Console](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/12/01/use-powershell-to-query-active-directory-from-the-console.aspx)

[Powershell script for Adding Active Directory Users to Sharepoint 2010 Groups](http://www.iotap.com/Blog/tabid/673/entryid/154/Powershell-script-for-Adding-Active-Directory-Users-to-Sharepoint-2010-Groups.aspx)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use the first link you posted, given that I don't have that feature in SharePoint 2010 Foundation.